C# - System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException
I am trying to set an icon for the System.Windows.Forms.Form and I get an error.
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
ERROR:
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "DSG_MailRoom.Form1.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "DSG_MailRoom" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'
I've tried deleting the icon, reimporting it, changing the name to something else and then setting that as the icon. Nothing seems to work.

This is not a big deal, the application compiles when I comment out this line, but would like to not have the default icon in the taskbar. Thanks in advance!
